I tried to Install appium using node.js "npm install -g appium" I was facing issue during installation
I was Trying to install Appium via node "npm install -g appium"
I was facing issue while downloading it .
I tried the Command which I mentioned above
Device OS : Windows 10
Actual Result :
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated rimraf@2.4.5: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@6.0.4: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
Expected Result:
I was supposed to get the Required Files downloaded .
Attachment of my Screen:
enter image description here

This seems to be throwing a deprecation warning when attempting to install Appium via npm. These warnings state that particular modules that are utilized by Appium have newer versions and the current versions being used contain some problems. However, they should not stop the installation from running successfully to the end.
npm install -g npm
npm cache clean --force

Then try:
npm install -g appium

